# Spring get bean only if already instanced for scope

Tags: spring, scope, javabeans, instance

Hi i'm using Spring 3

i'm using

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType
```

is there a possibility to get only the beans already instanciated for the current scope?

I don't want to instanciate Beans which have not already been used in the current request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that not, but you could write one, something like:

```
public static List<Object> getBeansInScope(Class<?> type, AbstractApplicationContext ctx, int scope) {
        List<Object> beans = new ArrayList<Object>();
        String[] names = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(type);
        RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

        for (String name : names) {
            Object bean = attributes.getAttribute(name, scope);
            if (bean != null) 
                beans.add(bean);
        }

        return beans;
    }
```

That only work for request and session scopes.

Comment: Use RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getViewScope() to get the attribute map.